# Getting less appraisal raise than your colleagues

Tags: salary, raise, appraisal

All my colleagues got a one on one call for appraisal but I didn't got any notification for the same.

Even though I heard all are getting double raise in salary but my colleagues are getting more than that.

How should I deal with this situation ?

Comment: Putting it bluntly: are you performing at the same level as your colleagues?

Answer (score 8):

Talk to your manager about your concerns.

Comment: This is definitely step 1.  I think it's highly unusual that you received no explanation about this but you should start with your manager.

Answer (score 3):

> All my colleagues got a one on one call for appraisal but I didn't got
> any notification for the same.

If it is standard to have a one-on-one call with your manager as part of this process then reach out to them. Say something like: "I understand it is time for one-to-one meetings do you have an estimate regarding when our meting will be?"

Even if it isn't required to have a one-to-one meeting you still might want a meeting just to see where you stand performance wise.

> Even though I heard all are getting double raise in salary but my
> colleagues are getting more than that.

This statement can be an issue. You have two rumors: everybody is getting at least X, and some are getting more than that. You don't mention if you have already seen a bump in pay.

> How should I deal with this situation ?

Wait until  you have the meeting, or at least wait until your manager responds. The meeting should address not just your performance but compensation changes.